# How to increase bar width in google bar chart?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I understand `bar: { groupWidth: '100%'}` increase bar width to max.

But I need to show legend on right side, so i code `chartArea: { right:'60%'}` to create more space to show legend, it is causing no more space for bar width. Screenshot at below :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0fcG.jpg)

Is there any solution to make `bar: { groupWidth: '300%'}` or make `bar groupWidth` regardless `chartArea: { right:'60%'}` ?

```js
                       google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
                        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

                        function drawVisualization() {
                            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                                ['Plan', 'SEED FUND = USD50,000', 
                                'LOAN FUND = USD50,000', 
                                'PROFIT = USD3000'],               
                                ['MCF', 50000, 50000, 3000],
                            ]);

                            var options = {
                                title : { position: 'none'},
                                vAxis: {title: 'MCF Equity'},
                                hAxis: {title: 'USD'},
                                seriesType: 'bars',
                                series: {5: {type: 'line'}},
                                legend: {alignment: "center"},
                                chartArea: {top:10, bottom:80, left:'20%', right:'60%', 'width': '1000%' },
                                isStacked: true,
                                bar: { groupWidth: '200%'},
                               
                                hAxis: 
                                {
                                    viewWindow: 
                                    {
                                        min: 0,
                                        max: 6
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                            };

                            var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                            chart.draw(data, options);
                        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div" class="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just play around and got the solution accidentally.
Just change `max: 6` to `max: 3`

Demo :

```js
                       google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
                        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

                        function drawVisualization() {
                            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                                ['Plan', 'SEED FUND = USD50,000', 
                                'LOAN FUND = USD50,000', 
                                'PROFIT = USD3000'],               
                                ['MCF', 50000, 50000, 3000],
                            ]);

                            var options = {
                                title : { position: 'none'},
                                vAxis: {title: 'MCF Equity'},
                                hAxis: {title: 'USD'},
                                seriesType: 'bars',
                                series: {5: {type: 'line'}},
                                legend: {alignment: "center"},
                                chartArea: {top:10, bottom:80, left:'20%', right:'60%', 'width': '1000%' },
                                isStacked: true,
                                bar: { groupWidth: '200%'},
                               
                                hAxis: 
                                {
                                    viewWindow: 
                                    {
                                        min: 0,
                                        max: 3
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                            };

                            var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                            chart.draw(data, options);
                        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div" class="chart"></div>
```